# React not loading form input field. No errors, just nothing being rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new to this, so I'm assuming it's a stupid little problem that I'm unware of.

I have form that renders input lines based off the amount of setpoints it gets from the backend. I have put in several console.log, and they all function fine until I get to the input.jsx. My console.log() in input never gets called, and the code just seems to.. forget about the input.

main code:

```
import React from "react";
import Joi from "joi-browser";

import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/button";

import Form from "./common/form";
import axios from "axios";

class SetpointsModal extends Form {
  state = {
    data: {},
    errors: {},
  };

  schema = {};

  doSubmit = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.put(
      `/api/${this.props.id}_setpoints`,
      this.state.data
    );
    console.log(data);
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/${this.props.id}_setpoints`);
    Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
      this.schema[key] = Joi.number().label(data[key].label);
    });
    this.setState({ data });
  }

  render() {
    const { title, show, handleClose } = this.props;
    return (
      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>{title} Setpoints</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Modal.Body>
            {Object.keys(this.state.data).forEach((field) => {
              this.renderInput(field);
            })}
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            {this.renderBtn("Update")}
            <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
              Close
            </Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </form>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

export default SetpointsModal;
```

Handle submit + render Input:

```
 handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const errors = this.validate();
    console.log(errors);
    this.setState({ errors: errors || {} });
    if (errors) return;

    this.doSubmit();
  };

  renderInput(name) {
    const { errors } = this.state;
    const { label, data } = this.state.data[name];
    console.log(name);
    return (
      <Input
        name={name}
        label={label}
        value={data}
        error={errors[name]}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
```

Input:

```
import React from "react";

const Input = ({ name, label, error, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
      <input {...rest} id={name} name={name} className="form-control" />
      {error && <div className="alert alert-danger">{error}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` here won't be doing what you want it to do; it will 'do' something on each iteration but won't 'return' anything.

Using `map` might be more in line with what you were hoping for ([docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)); this will return an array of components which will render out.

I'd suggest the following change in your `render` (you will need to pass a `key` down to each Input from your function):

```
  {Object.keys(this.state.data).map((field, key) => (
    this.renderInput(field, key);
  ))}
```